# Updating bounding box of layer using geoserver API

Tags: geoserver, extents

Is there a way to **set** the Bounding Box of a geoserver layer using the REST Api? I get the BB extent using a postgis query and then I could pass it to a json or xml and post it. But I haven't found any examples online.

I read that gsconfig doesn't support this functionality. 
My geoserver version is rather old (2.5).

Comment: I found this: http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/geowebcache/rest/layers.html  It seems you can use the geowebcache rest api (available also in geoserver 2.5) to modify a layer.

Comment: Not sure to understand but geoserver calculate the BBOX when inserting the layer with Rest. If the bbox changes you can delete and re-create the layer.

Comment: I know that geoserver Rest calculates the bounding box when the layer is CREATED. What I need is to programmatically change the bounding box without dropping the layer completely.

Comment: Assuming this is a vector layer.

Check this ReST call: http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/rest/api/featuretypes.html#workspaces-ws-datastores-ds-featuretypes-ft-format notice the recalculate parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You should update the `FeatureType` of your layer. [The feature type API](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/featuretypes.html#workspaces-ws-datastores-ds-featuretypes-ft-format) is useful for this purpose.
You can use Geoserver-manager (java library) for calling rest APIs.

```
GeoServerRESTManager manager = new GeoServerRestManager(url,user,pass);
manager.getPublisher().publishDBLayer(...);
```

Comment: This answer is ok, but the link is broken. I suggest switching to this: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/featuretypes.html#workspaces-ws-datastores-ds-featuretypes-ft-format

Comment: Thanks @AndréCarvalho